# kubernetes isn't overriding environment variables that were set in the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, kubernetes

My Dockerfile contains default environment variables for development and testing scenarios:

```
ENV mysql_host=mysql \
    mysql_user=app \
    mysql_password=password \
```

and my k8s yaml contains an env directive:

```
spec:
  containers:
    env:
      - name: "mysql_password"
        value: "someotherpassword"
        name: "mysql_host"
        value: "someotherhost"
        name: "mysql_user"
        value: "someotheruser"
```

but when I exec into my running container with

```
kubctl exec -it service -- /bin/bash
```

I'm still seeing "password" as mysql_password .

edit: added more from the k8s yaml for completeness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to declare all the variables in the the correct yaml format
so in this exmaple  mysql_password will override the variable but mysql_password2 will not override and will only be inserted if its not declared already :

```
spec:
  containers:
    env:
      - name: mysql_password     
        value: "someotherpassword"
      - name: mysql_password2
        value: "password" 
      - name: override_password
        value: password3
```

meaning if it started with a "-" it will override . otherwise it will insert the variable to the container

Comment: I think adding the '-' to 'name' makes it valid YAML rather than making it insert / override

Answer (score 4):

Hmm may I suggest a better approach to storing and retrieving secrets for your containers?

Kubernetes provides you with the concepts of [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) when the data you are using is sensitive, and [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configmap/) when it is not.

You can specify in your pod definition that the container should pull the values from a secret like below (Kubernetes 1.6+)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata: 
  labels: 
    context: docker-k8s-lab
    name: mysql-pod
  name: mysql-pod
spec: 
  containers:
  - image: "mysql:latest"
    name: mysql
    ports: 
    - containerPort: 3306
    envFrom:
      secretRef:
        name: mysql-secret
```

So now you can have 2 different secrets, one for prod and one for test

test-secret.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  MYSQL_USER: <user>
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: <password>
  MYSQL_DATABASE: <database>
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <root_password>
```

prod-secret.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  MYSQL_USER: <user>
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: <password>
  MYSQL_DATABASE: <database>
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <root_password>
```

Now you can deploy the secrets in to the respective clusters

```
kubectl config use-context test
kubectl create -f dev-secret.yaml

kubectl config use-context prod
kubectl create -f prod-secret.yaml
```

Now when your Pod starts it will populate the env from the values in the secret.

Comment: that's all fine and well but my question was about overriding the default env values that were set in the dockerfile. why would this work compared to a simple env variable?

Comment: @NiPR, both approaches will _work_, but one approach stores passwords in cleartext in source control, while the other stores them securely.  I.e. one approach you should follow, and the other you should never do.